# In Apache Pulsar is it possible to find out which namespace bundles are assigned to each broker?

Tags: apache-pulsar

Is there some way via the Admin CLI or other tooling to find out which namespace bundles are assigned to a particular broker?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `pulsar-admin` client invoking the `brokers namespaces` command

```
./pulsar-admin --admin-url http://pulsar-broker:8080 brokers namespaces \
              --url my-broker.my-deployment.k8s-namespace.svc.cluster.local:8080 \
              cluster-name
```

which will return something like the following

```
"tenant/ns2/0xf0000000_0xf2000000    [broker_assignment=shared is_controlled=false is_active=true]"
"tenant/ns1/0x44000000_0x46000000    [broker_assignment=shared is_controlled=false is_active=true]"
"tenant/ns1/0xf0000000_0xf2000000    [broker_assignment=shared is_controlled=false is_active=true]"
"tenant/event/0x74000000_0x76000000    [broker_assignment=shared is_controlled=false is_active=true]"
"tenant/ns2/0x5c000000_0x5e000000    [broker_assignment=shared is_controlled=false is_active=true]"
```